# What do they mean when they say “ by the domain”

Tags: meaning

I am a foreigner and I am not sure that I understand the meaning of “ Hotels North Austin by the Domain” Does this mean that hotels in this area are under some form of control of the government/state ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct spelling is "The Domain", which is the name of a large office, retail, and residential centre in the northwestern part of Austin, Texas, USA. "By" can mean "near or close to". Consider the fragment to mean "Hotels in North Austin, near to The Domain".

[The Domain (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Domain_(Austin,_Texas))